# Solr update command with authentication

Tags: solr

Is there a way to add username/password parameters to the following solr update command?

```
...........jdk7x64\bin\java -jar -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update post.jar test_data.xml
```

Or is there any other way to post files to a Solr which is password protected?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below command, Hope this will help.

```
jdk7x64\bin\java -jar -Durl=http://username:password@localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update post.jar test_data.xml
```

Adding the `username:password` in the url just before the `hostname`.

According to [Solr Issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5960), it is available from **Solr 4.8**.